# Characterization of $l_p$ up to a linear isometry

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, convex-geometry

There is a science called "Geometry of Banach spaces". I wonder if they managed to give a geometric characterization of $\ell_p$ ($p\in[1,\infty]$) up to isometric isomorphism (among all Banach spaces)?

For $p=1,\infty$ this seems to be not difficult, at least in finite dimensional case. For example, the unit ball in $\ell_\infty$ (over $\mathbb R$) of dimension $n$ has $2^n$ extreme points, while in $\ell_1$ it has $2n$ extreme points, and that is why $\ell_\infty$ and $\ell_1$ can't be isometrically isomorphic (unless $\dim\le 2$). On the other hand, for a Banach space $X$ of dimension $n$ having $2^n$ extreme points in the unit ball is not enough for being isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_\infty$ (since it is easy to construct a norm with arbitrary given (enough big, even) number of extreme points in the unit ball).

So what is the geometric explanation? I asked this in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808064/characterization-of-the-finite-dimensional-l-infty-l-1-l-p-up-to-a-line) without success. Is it possible that nobody considered this?

Comment: Of course the classification of $L_p$ spaces, both isometric and isomorphic, is very well understood. You do not say just what you want. Have you looked in any books?

Comment: Bill, this classification where is it described? And what is not clear in my question?

Comment: I mean, what precisely are you looking for?  Is it  "for what $p$ and $r$ and $n$ is $\ell_p^n$ isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_r^n$"?

Comment: After all, there are books written about the isometric classification of Hilbert spaces with the category of Banach spaces.

Comment: Bill, of course I mean another thing. The question is which geometric properties of (the unit ball in) a Banach space $X$ allow us to conclude that $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_p^n$. And I don't ask about Hilbert spaces.

Comment: For example, as far as I understand, the following statement is true: a Banach space $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_1^n$, $n\in{\mathbb N}$, if and only if $\dim X=n$, and the unit ball of $X$ has exactly $2n$ extreme points. Is something similar true, say, for $\ell_\infty^n$?

Comment: How about: "$X$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_\infty^n$ iff $\dim X = n$ and the unit ball of $X^*$ has exactly $2n$ extreme points"?  Seems pretty artificial to me, but there it is.  What kind of characterization do you imagine for $p \notin \{1, 2, \infty\}$?

Comment: Well, you can make it less artificial by saying "$\dim X = n$ and the unit ball of $X$ has exactly $2n$ facets."

Comment: @Mark Meckes: I think, this depends on the definition of facet. And I have no idea about $p\notin\{1,2,\infty\}$, I thought this must be digged up.

Comment: $\ell_\infty^*$ is characterized by being the only $n$ dimensional space that is norm one complemented in every superspace.  Or you can say that a certain numerical parameter (MacPhail constant or the parameter Figiel and I introduced) is extremal. $$$$ Deschaseaux, Jean-Pierre
Une caractérisation de certains espaces vectoriels normés de dimension finie par leur constante de Macphail. (French) 
C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A-B 276 (1973), A1349–A1351. $$$$Figiel, T.; Johnson, W. B.
Large subspaces of ln∞ and estimates of the Gordon-Lewis constant. 
Israel J. Math. 37 (1980), no. 1-2, 92–112.

Comment: Bill, first, excuse me, what is $\ell_\infty^*$? And that is interesting, of course, but it sounds not quite geometrically, more in terms of category theory.

Comment: Typo; $\ell_\infty^n$.

Comment: And what about other $\ell_p$?

Comment: @Mark Meckes: is there a direct way to define facet, other than "extreme point of the polar"?

Comment: A facet of a polytope $P$ is an intersection of $P$ with a bounding hyperplane, which has maximal dimension among such intersections.  There are probably other equivalent definitions.  This should be in any book on convex geometry.

Comment: Mark, if we take this definition of facet, then for an absorbing bounded balanced convex set $B$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$ having 6 facets is not equivalent to being a unit ball for a space isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_\infty^3$. You can take $B=\{x\in {\mathbb R}^3: \ \max_i|x_i|\le 1\quad \&\quad x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\le 2\}$ (the intersection of a cube with the edge 2 and the usual ball of radius $\sqrt{2}$) -- this set has 6 facets but it is not a cube.

Comment: Ah, I see... You mean that the unit ball (of the norm) must be a polytope, and in addition it must have $2n$ facets. Is this true? Anyway, this looks too complicated... Is there a way to describe the situation without the additional assumption that the inut ball is a polytope?

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment:

Look at Wells and Williams book, Embeddings and extensions in analysis, Springer Ergebnisse 84.  There you find the classical description of what spaces $X$ embed isometrically in an $L_p$ space.  You also need $X^*$ to embed isometrically into $L_q$, $1/p+1/q=1$. There are finite dimensional spaces other than $\ell_p$ spaces that satisfy this (e.g. Hilbert spaces), so this is not a characterization of $\ell_p$.  But perhaps the only finite dimensional spaces that satisfy this are $p$ sums of Hilbert spaces. Maybe that question has been considered; I don't know.

If you are willing to take "having a $1$ symmetric basis" as a geometric condition (after all, that just says that the group of isometries is large) then the problem is much easier because for $1<p \not=2<\infty$ the space $\ell_p^n$ has a unique (up to normalizing and changing sign) $1$-symmetric basis.

Comment: Bill, before I find this reading, what is "1 symmetric basis"?

Comment: $\|\sum \pm a_i e_{\pi(i)} \| = \|\sum a_i e_i\|$ for all permutations $\pi$ and all choices of signs.

Comment: Ah, OK, thank you. Do your words mean that infinite dimensional $\ell_\infty$ were not characterised?

Comment: Infinite dimensional $1$-injective spaces are just $C(K)$ with $K$ extremally disconnected, or order complete abstract $M$-spaces, or commutative von Neumann algebras, or... The $\ell_\infty$ spaces are the purely atomic lattices within the class of $1$-injective spaces.

Comment: Bill, that idea with facets, did it get any formalization in the question about $\ell_\infty$?

Comment: Mark was just dualizing the extreme point condition that characterizes $\ell_1^n$.  I don't know an infinite dimensional version of that, although I guess you could get one by dualizing the characterization of $\ell_1$ spaces as those $L_1$ spaces whose unit ball is the closed convex hull of the extreme points.  The characterizations of $\ell_\infty^n$ I mentioned that involve numerical parameters only apply to finite dimensional spaces.